# How to read a web page content which may itself be redirected to another url?

Tags: perl

I'm using this code to read the web page content:

```
     my $ua = new LWP::UserAgent;                     
      my $response= $ua->post($url);

      if ($response->is_success){                 
      my $content = $response->content;
...
```

But if $url is pointing to moved page then $response->is_success is returning false. Now how do I get the content of redirected page easily?

Answer (score 1):

You need to chase the redirect itself.

```
if ($response->is_redirect()) {
    $url = $response->header('Location');
    # goto try_again
}
```

You may want to put this in a while loop and use "next" instead of "goto".  You may also want to log it, limit the number of redirections you are willing to chase, etc.

[update]

OK I just noticed there is an easier way to do this.  From the man page of LWP::UserAgent:

```
$ua->requests_redirectable
$ua->requests_redirectable( \@requests )
    This reads or sets the object's list of request names that
    "$ua->redirect_ok(...)" will allow redirection for.  By default,
    this is "['GET', 'HEAD']", as per RFC 2616.  To change to include
    'POST', consider:

       push @{ $ua->requests_redirectable }, 'POST';
```

So yeah, maybe just do that.  :-)

Comment: It seems GET requests are automatically redirected internally. So I'm doing this way:  my $agent = LWP::UserAgent->new(env_proxy => 1,keep_alive => 1, timeout => 30, agent => "Mozilla/4.76 [en] (Win98; U)");
     my $header = HTTP::Request->new(GET => $link);

     my $request = HTTP::Request->new('GET', $link, $header);

      my $response = $agent->request($request)

Comment: Yes, but your question used `POST`, which you need to configure (or handle) manually.  Anyway, glad you got it working.

Comment: My mistake, I need to access only the web pages(GET). Well this common way works for both GET & POST.